# $x$ is either an element of $S$ or a limit point of $S$ if and only if every open set containing $x$ intersects $S$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, $S\subset X$ and $x\in X$.

Can I show that:

$x$ is either an element of $S$ or a limit point of $S$ if and only if every open set containing $x$ intersects $S$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is  just a matter of applying the definition and splitting  into two cases, (1) $x \in S$ and (2) $x \notin S$.

If $x \in S$, then clearly every open set containing $x$ must intersect $S$.
if $x \notin S$ and $x$ is a limit point of $S$, then every open set containing $x$ contains a point of $S$.

Now suppose every open set containing $x$ intersects $S$. If $x \in S$, we are finished, so suppose $ x \notin S$. Since every open set containing $x$ contains a point of $S$, we see that $x$ is a limit point of $S$.